# Is it possible to create armor with Smaug scales?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, smaug

I haven't read the book, but I've read in some wiki that Smaug died by the black arrow and fell so the corpse still remains. Is it possible to skin the dragon and make armor with his scales?

Comment: *"How much it will weigh?"*  42.

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: You might find a better answer to this over on the [RPG version of this site](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Hobbit:

> They removed northward higher up the shore; for ever after they had a dread of the water where the dragon lay. He would never again return to his golden bed, but was stretched cold as stone, twisted upon the floor of the shallows. There for ages his huge bones could be seen in calm weather amid the ruined piles of the old town. But few dared to cross the cursed spot, and none dared to dive into the shivering water or recover the precious stones that fell from his rotting carcass.

According to this passage, (1) the dragon's skin rotted following his death, so that only bones were left, and (2) there was a taboo on visiting the site of his death anyway.

So your answer is "no".

As for how much it would weigh, Tolkien just doesn't give us that kind of information.

Comment: Advance warning: if you ask for a guess to the second part of your question, you run the risk of it being closed as Primarily Opinion-Based.